# How to combine together WebViewWidget and WillPopScope

Tags: flutter, webview, back-button

How can I use WillPopScope with WebViewWidget in Flutter? I only found examples with WebView. With WillPopScope I would need that, when the back button is pressed, it returns to the page https://www.example.com, i.e. the home page of the webview.

This is my code at the moment:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: WebViewExample()));

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewExampleState createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  bool showErrorPage = false;

  WebViewController controller = WebViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller.setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
      onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
        setState(() {
          showErrorPage = true;
        });
      },
    ));

    controller.setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);

    controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: showErrorPage 
      ? const Center(
        child: Text('Error!'),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      )
      : WebViewWidget (
        controller: controller,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://www.example.com/'));
    return Scaffold(
      body: showErrorPage 
      ? const Center(
        child: Text('Error!'),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      )
      : WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () => _goBack(context),
        child: WebViewWidget(
          controller: controller,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _goBack(BuildContext context) async {
     controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://www.example.com/'));
     return Future.value(false);
  }
```